# Vignere cipher is not returning correct encryption and ecryption

Tags: python, function, class, encryption, return

I am trying to create a vignere cipher class that has the function to
encrypt and decipher, vignere ciphers.
However my code is returning the wrong characters and I was wondering if anyone
could help me identify my problem.

```
class Vignere():
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    self.enc_key = input("Please enter encription word: ")

  def vignere_encrypt(self, user_message):
    ex_key = self.enc_key
    ex_key_len = len(ex_key)
    user_len = len(user_message)
    cipher = ''
    self.enc_key.upper()
    while ex_key_len < user_len:
      ex_key = ex_key + self.enc_key
      ex_key_len = len(ex_key)

    key_pos = 0

    for letter in user_message.upper():
      if letter in self.alphabet:
        pos = self.alphabet.find(letter)
        key_char = ex_key[key_pos]
        key_char_pos = self.alphabet.find(key_char)
        key_pos = key_pos + 1
        new_pos = pos + key_char_pos

        if new_pos > 26:
          new_pos= new_pos - 26
        new_char = self.alphabet[new_pos]
        cipher = cipher + new_char

      else:
        cipher = cipher + letter
    return cipher

  def vignere_decipher(self, user_message):
    ex_key = self.enc_key
    ex_key_len = len(ex_key)
    user_len = len(user_message)
    cipher = ''
    self.enc_key.upper()
    while ex_key_len < user_len:
      ex_key = ex_key + self.enc_key
      ex_key_len = len(ex_key)

    key_pos = 0

    for letter in user_message.upper():
      if letter in self.alphabet:
        pos = self.alphabet.find(letter)
        key_char = ex_key[key_pos]
        key_char_pos = self.alphabet.find(key_char)
        key_pos = key_pos + 1
        new_pos = pos + key_char_pos

        if new_pos > 26:
          new_pos= new_pos + 26
        new_char = self.alphabet[new_pos]
        cipher = cipher + new_char

      else:
        cipher = cipher + letter
    return cipher
```

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any example with input, output and what you were expecting?

Comment: For example with the input of the encryption word being "shift" and the word to encrypt being "car" the output I would want would be UHZ. However I am getting BZQ.

Comment: And what have you tried to do to debug this code?

Answer (score 0):

> For example with the input of the encryption word being "shift" and the word to encrypt being "car" the output I would want would be UHZ. However I am getting BZQ

Quick analysis: C -> pos==2, key_char==i, aaaand...key_char_pos==-1 Because your key is lowercase.

Let's see your code:

You have `self.enc_key.upper()` which doesn't change anything - string are immutable, any operation in string returns a new result.

I'd recommend removing those lines and just add .upper in init:

```
self.enc_key = input("Please enter encription word: ").upper()
```